# How do I check if a Resource Group already exists in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I'm trying to improve my logic and make the code more efficient!  Currently I'm checking to see whether a Resource Group exists - if it does, random numbers are appended to the $resGroup variable.   I think it would more logical if I checked to see if the $resGroup + $num is checked for existence..  Any advice would be appreciated.

```
#LOGIN TO AZURE - DISPLAYS LOGIN DIALOG
Login-AzureRmAccount

#RESOURCEGROUP
$resGroup = "group"

#WEB APP 1
$WebAppName1 = "FirstApp" + $resGroup
$WebAppLocation1 = "Southeast Asia"

#WEB APP 2
$WebAppName2 = "SecondApp" + $resGroup
$WebAppLocation2 = "southcentralus"

$resGrpChk = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $resGroup -ev notPresent -ea 0


if (!$resGrpChk)
{  
#CREATES A NEW RESOURCE GROUP
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resGroup -Location "West Europe"    
Write-Host 'RESOURCE GROUP CREATED' -fore white -back green
   }
 else
 {
   $num = Get-Random -Maximum 999
   $newGroup = "group"
   $resGroup = $group + $num
   New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resGroup -Location "West Europe"  
 }
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Updated the heading to something more appropriate.  Guess I'm asking where the best place the check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would suggest you implement something like a loop to check for the existence of resource group and change the name:

```
$name = 'group'

do {
    $rg = Get-AzureRMResourceGroup -Name $name -ev break
    if (!$break) { $name = $name + (get-random -maximum 1000) }
} while (!$break)
```

the only downside is that the name would get concatenated, so you would have group354, and then group 354678, but this can be worked around with something like `$name = $name -replace ".{3}$"`, well you get the idea.